# Scrolling won't work after scrollTop Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After clicking the small div with the `^` character at the bottom of the screen, the scroll animation is launched normally.
But after doing it multiple time and when you try to scroll down, it will stick up for a certain time (proportional to the number of times you clicked on the div).

Can someone tell me why it does this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="test">Where to go</div>
   <div id="goToTop">^</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    var currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(st == currentScrollTop){
      var yPosInAbsolute = window.innerHeight - 100;
      $('#goToTop').css({'top': st + yPosInAbsolute, 'right': 100});

      $('#goToTop').show();
      $('#goToTop').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#test').offset().top - 50}, 2000);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      });
    }else{
      $('#goToTop').hide();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

The **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/moyodeza/2/edit)**

Comment: That certain time is the timeouts & animation time stacks.

Comment: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/sCaLr/1/) My try goes waste coz of quick answer. Anyhow try it :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need jQuery's [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. This is because animation calls are queued.

```
$('html,body').stop(true, false).animate(...)
```

[See](http://jsbin.com/silecija/2/edit)

Comment: this is still buggy. it's not working all the time. i have tiles of divs beside eachother, in mobile it's one on each line. when you click on one it expands and scrolls to the top of the opened div. when u click on several boxes, it keeps on dragging the page to the last clicked. u can't stay in one place. i guess i shuold solve this differently

Comment: @Amjo second parameter of .stop() method is about stopping current animation. Try reading the docs, there's a link in my answer. Try .stop(true, true) – it should immediately jump to the final destination of the animation.
If you need to stop where you are in the moment of click, you probably should remember current scroll position in the moment of click and, after jquery jumps to the final position of animation (via requestAnimationFrame or zero timeout), use remembered position to manually update scroll. Should work seamlessly (without visible jumps), but requires experimenting.